# SWT Spy doesn't seem to be fully installed

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt

I'm trying to use the Eclipse plugin [SWT spy](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php) from the SWT Development Tools. I installed it, and it seems to be installed correctly (ie, I see it on the list of installed software), but when I try to show the view, there is no SWT Tools category and typing swt doesn't show anything.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled SWT Tools, ran Eclipse as administrator, and reinstalled the tools. When I restarted after that, I was able to see the view.

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipse 4.7 SWT Spy is included in Eclipse PDE. As an example, you can can get it by downloading the Eclipse for RCP and RAP.

To launch SWT Spy, press: CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + F9

In case of doubts, please see: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#swt-spy